# Can't resolve an object initiated in a public method?

Tags: java, object, methods, public, resolve

I'm just starting out with java and I was working on a new GUI. I made a method that makes my JFrame, sets its default location, close operation, background colour etc.

I made a separate method for this to keep it out of the main code for the sake of tidiness. I already know how to solve this method if I just put all of those things in the main method.

This is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void makeWindow(){
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        makeWindow();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

I get an error in my main method saying that "mainWindow" can't be resolved. Why is this? is it because I made the mainWindow object in the other method? Is there a way to resolve this issue without putting everything from the makeWindow() method into the main method?

Comment: mainWindow is local to the method makeWindow(). It's all about scope.

Comment: Here's an external guide for scope: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: I noticed that mainWindow was local, but mainWindow is an object, how can I make an instance object? I already know I can declare instance variables outside their respective methods but how can I do the same for an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because `mainWindow` only exists in the context of your `makeWindow` method. You can make it a static field instead:

```
public class Main {

    private static JFrame mainWindow; // declare it here so it can be seen from your main method.

    public static void makeWindow(){
        mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        makeWindow();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Xing commented (credits shared), you can return the `mainWindow` from your `makeWindow` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static JFrame makeWindow(){
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        return mainWindow;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame mainWindow = makeWindow();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Clarified it for me!

Comment: Also, you can return the mainWindow from makeWindow() method and assign it to a variable in main method

Comment: Oh yeah I hadn't though of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Psear please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

create mainWindow instance/ reference globally

```
private static JFrame mainWindow;

public static void makeWindow(){
    mainWindow = new JFrame();
}
```